# Why is my query result in page so slow, while the query itself is fast

Tags: mysql, performance, phpmyadmin

In `phpMyAdmin` I run a query which takes around 8-9 seconds to display results (just few resutls, but the join is between 2 big tables).

What makes me wonder is that `phpMyAdmin` reports `Query took 0.0103 seconds`, while I have to wait much more to see results.

What is the explanation?

Query looks like:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.name 
FROM table as t1 
JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id=t2.user_id
ORDER BY t1.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 5000 -- is it because of this?
```

Also, from those 5000 results there are displayed only 25 at a time.

Does `phpMyAdmin` load all those 5000 rows in background so that you can do operations?

Comment: How about you leave the LIMIT clause off and test what happens?

Comment: It loads very fast. So I guess m explanation is right, right?

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` probably does a count(*) on the original query, or similar activity that runs the full query

Comment: But is know the total number of rows also when you use no limit...

Answer (score 0):

(When asking questions like this, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.)

Adding this index to `t2` will *probably* speed things up on both situations:

```
INDEX(user_id, name)
```